# extracting ordered list of spatial points from JSON into PostgreSQL array

Tags: postgresql, spatial, jsonb

i have JSONB data in PostgreSQL that looks like the following:

```
{"datasetGPolygon": [
  {
    "datasetGPolygonOuterGRing": {
      "gRingPoint": [
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.922935,
          "gRingLongitude": -125.687365
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.639177,
          "gRingLongitude": -126.126729
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.382373,
          "gRingLongitude": -125.555556
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.553726,
          "gRingLongitude": -125.02832
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.95122,
          "gRingLongitude": -124.852575
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 50.289339,
          "gRingLongitude": -125.204066
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 50.261254,
          "gRingLongitude": -125.99492
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.922935,
          "gRingLongitude": -125.687365
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "datasetGPolygonOuterGRing": {
      "gRingPoint": [
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.292889,
          "gRingLongitude": -124.843625
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.60003,
          "gRingLongitude": -124.843625
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.60003,
          "gRingLongitude": -124.409753
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.292889,
          "gRingLongitude": -124.409753
        },
        {
          "gRingLatitude": 49.292889,
          "gRingLongitude": -124.843625
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]}
```

i'd like to convert it to as many arrays as there are "datasetGPolygonOuterGRing" objects that preserves the order of the points in each "gRingPoint". the above would provide two records:

```
[[[48.592142,-123.920288],[48.645205,-123.667603],[48.5262,-123.940887],[48.592142,-123.920288]],
[[48.592147,-123.920292],[48.645210,-123.667607],[48.5267,-123.940893],[48.592147,-123.920292]]]
```

i've tried several PostgreSQL JSON functions that extract all of the points into their own records which is clearly not desired.

Edit: i have figured out a solution as the following.

```
with poly as (select poly.n n1, poly.points points from submission, jsonb_path_query(eml_json_source, '$.**.datasetGPolygon[*].datasetGPolygonOuterGRing.gRingPoint') with ordinality poly(points, n)),
points as (select poly.n1, arr.position n2, arr.point->>'gRingLatitude' lat, arr.point->>'gRingLongitude' long from poly,
jsonb_array_elements(points) with ordinality arr(point, position))
select array_agg('['||lat||','||long||']' order by n2) from points group by n1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=93d068d74458abba95db424bc7e187cb

but would be interested in whether there is a "better" way to do this? would some implementation of lateral joins make it less verbose?

Comment: Valid JSON only has distinct key names, you cannot have duplicate `datasetGPolygonOuterGRing` keys https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3e9d9db95eebad673de63f7b00c9abd6. What does your JSON *really* look like?

Comment: sorry, i've adjusted the example to make it obvious that we are dealing with an array of ```datasetGPolygonOuterGRing``` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not necessary to group, as long as you unnest the inner array in a subquery...

```
SELECT (
    SELECT array_agg('['||(arr.pt->>'gRingLatitude')||','||(arr.pt->>'gRingLongitude')||']' ORDER BY arr.n)
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(gp.poly->'datasetGPolygonOuterGRing'->'gRingPoint') WITH ORDINALITY arr(pt, n)
  ) arr
FROM submission s
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(s.eml_json_source->'datasetGPolygon') gp(poly);
```

... or in a lateral join

```
SELECT v.arr
FROM submission s
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(s.eml_json_source->'datasetGPolygon') gp(poly)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg('['||(arr.pt->>'gRingLatitude')||','||(arr.pt->>'gRingLongitude')||']' ORDER BY arr.n)
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(gp.poly->'datasetGPolygonOuterGRing'->'gRingPoint') WITH ORDINALITY arr(pt, n)
) v(arr);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f1d7177f9301f1af288231780a05b8aa)